# Building GUI the Declarative way

Tags: gui, gui-builder, qt, go

When talking about RAD (Rapid Application Development) Tool under Linux/Unix, I used to use Tk, which is a fairly easy library for building graphical applications, to build *simple* GUI based applications, because to me, GTK, Qt, or Java are *way* too complicated to be use to build *simple* GUI based applications. Maybe they are designed to build *complicated* ones.

> The core concept of Tk is that GUIs are built out of widgets -- objects like buttons, windows, scrollbars, and menus, which have associated attributes (size, colour, captions, and so on). Widgets are grouped together hierarchically within a toplevel window...
>
> The general structure of a Tcl/Tk program is to define the user interface as a hierarchy of widgets with subroutines executed by callbacks. Widgets show up on the screen when you ask a geometry manager to manage them, or when you invoke the pack command (to resize the widget's parent to hold them).
>
> -- [Rapid Application Development Tools](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/linux/shopper/164.rad-tools.html)

The reason I quote above is to show how easy is to code such GUI based applications by hand in Tk.

The key idea is that you "declare" the GUI, instead of drawing it by hand (like in Visual Basic). There are so many drawing-based GUI tools (like glade, etc), but very very few declarative ones. I'm wondering what they are.

While looking for answers myself, I found the following is the kind of declarative GUI building tools I'm looking for (although I don't know what Oz stands for). you can see how simple declaration can be used for creating windows, adding children to them, and making them react to user input, etc.

`functor 
import 
   Application(exit)
   System(show)
   GTK
define 
   %% Define Toplevel window class
   class MyToplevel from GTK.window 
      meth new()
         GTK.window, new(GTK.'WINDOW_TOPLEVEL')
         GTK.window, setBorderWidth(10)
         GTK.window, setTitle("Hello, World!")
         {self signalConnect('delete-event' 
                             deleteEvent _)}
      end 
      meth deleteEvent(Args)
         %% Do cleanup stuff here
         {System.show 'deleteEvent occured'}
         {Application.exit 0}
      end 
   end 
   %% Define HelloButton class
   class HelloButton from GTK.button 
      meth new()
         GTK.button, newWithLabel("Hello, World!")
         GTK.button, signalConnect('clicked' 
                                   clickedEvent _)
      end 
      meth clickedEvent(Args)
         {System.show 'ClickedEvent occured'}
      end 
   end 
   %% Create Class Instances
   Toplevel = {New MyToplevel new()}
   Button   = {New HelloButton new()}
   %% Make Butten child of Toplevel Container
   {Toplevel add(Button)}
   %% Make it all visible
   {Toplevel showAll()}
end`

So, again, what are the popular declarative GUI building tools out there? (I'm actually more interested with those that [work with Go](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/go-qml/P_jkCWRyF1g/MdjKc1f5DgAJ), but that's not the restrain to this question)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library called **[libui](https://github.com/andlabs/libui)**.

> **libui** is a simple and portable (but not inflexible) GUI library in C that uses the native GUI technologies of each platform it supports.

When you use this library, you write a GUI program instead of "drag-drop" GUI components. I don't know what "declare" exactly means. But, I assume that "declare" is the code keywords is easily to understand. This library is not only available for C but also [Go](https://github.com/andlabs/ui). Here is a simple GUI program I taken from [libui tutorial](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/wiki/Getting-Started):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/andlabs/ui"
)

func main() {
    err := ui.Main(func() {
        name := ui.NewEntry()
        button := ui.NewButton("Greet")
        greeting := ui.NewLabel("")
        box := ui.NewVerticalBox()
        box.Append(ui.NewLabel("Enter your name:"), false)
        box.Append(name, false)
        box.Append(button, false)
        box.Append(greeting, false)
        window := ui.NewWindow("Hello", 200, 100, false)
        window.SetChild(box)
        button.OnClicked(func(*ui.Button) {
            greeting.SetText("Hello, " + name.Text() + "!")
        })
        window.OnClosing(func(*ui.Window) bool {
            ui.Quit()
            return true
        })
        window.Show()
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

It will produce a GUI program like this:

[image: example-libgui-go-program]

Comment: This is the best answer *so far*.

Answer (score 1):

## Vaadin

For building the GUI of a web app in pure Java, consider the [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com) open-source framework.

Vaadin works exactly as you describe, specifying in code the layout of a form, adding each widget (labels, fields, buttons, etc.). You then add chunks of code to be executed as the user manipulates the widgets at runtime.

Vaadin is similar in idea to Java Swing, but much simpler, better engineered, better thought-out, and much more practical and reliable.

Search for similar Questions here where I have posted more detailed discussions on Vaadin.

Comment: Thanks Basil, I found it "works on any HTML5 based stack" as well. That's a plus. Oh, and Vaadin Charts as well (Commercial license). I'd surely pick this one had there not been a Go solution. Still, +1.

Comment: How is this declarative?